# Determine if observable has changed in computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am implementing a cache function in a computed observable.

Is there any way to invalidate the cache below if the `items` collection differs since the last call?

I have seen examples of dirty checking where a serialized version of the observable is used to determine if the collection has changed, but it's too expensive for me, since there may be hundreds of items.

```
var itemCache;

var manipulatedItems = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    var items = someObervable();
    if(!itemCache /* || someObervable.hasChangedSinceLastCall */) {
        itemCache = heavyWork(items);
    }
    return itemCache;
});

var heavyWork = function(items){
    // do some heavy computing with items 
    return alteredItems;
};
```

In my viewmodel:

```
myViewModel.itemList = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    var result = manipulatedItems();
    return result;
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that you don't already have? Observables are cached. If `someObservable` hasn't changed, `manipulatedItems` just returns its cached value; it doesn't re-execute every time you get its value. When `someObservable` changes, Knockout will update the cached value.

Comment: @RoyJ Ah, I wasn't aware of that it didn't get re-executed every time. Problem solved by knockout then I guess :) Thanks!

Comment: Note that setting the `someObservable` might still trigger more re-evaluations than you'd like. For example, if it's an observable array you want to make sure you're not pushing items to it one by one. You could add a `console.log` to your `pureComputed` if you want to get a feel for how many times the value is evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since computed observables always cache the last value, there's no reason to store it separately. In fact, storing it separately can cause trouble with getting the latest data in your application.

```
var manipulatedItems = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    var items = someObervable();
    return heavyWork(items);
});

var heavyWork = function (items) {
    // do some heavy computing with items 
    return alteredItems;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to use `.subscribe` and keep the relevant moments in vars inside your own closure. There is no "last-modified-moment" property on observables or inside ko utils to be found.

In your repro, you could do something like this:

```
var lastChange = new Date();
var lastCacheRebuild = null;
var itemCache;

someObervable.subscribe(function(newObsValue) { lastChange = new Date(); });

var manipulatedItems = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    var items = someObervable();
    if(!itemCache || !lastCacheRebuild || lastChange > lastCacheRebuild) {
        lastCacheRebuild = new Date();
        itemCache = heavyWork(items);
    }
    return itemCache;
});
```

As far as the repro is concerned you could even put the `items = someObservable()` bit inside the `if` block.

PS. This is *not* recursive, i.e. the subscription is only on `someObservable` itself, not on the observable properties of things *inside* that observable. You'd have to manually craft that, which is specific to the structure of someObservable.

Comment: Wouldn't `lastChange > lastCacheRebuild` always evaluate as `true` since the `lastChange = new Date()` subscription will always happen _just_ before the subscription created in the `pureComputed`? Any changes to `someObservable` will always trigger evaluation of both functions, no?

Comment: @user3297291 Hmm, you're right, at the least on some points. I'd better make a real repro to demo this, so I can also fix the implementation details. Might take a bit before I get to that though. In the mean time, I'll leave this answer, because the basic idea of this answer would remain intact: "use a subscription".